# How to use a self-signed SSL certificate when developing with Trigger.io?

Tags: ios, ssl, triggers, trigger.io, self-signed

Our backend is in rails, and for several reasons the development environment has to be run with rails using a self-signed SSL certificate. This works fine on the desktop after manually trusting the certificate.

Using Trigger.io, we're developing a mobile application targeting iOS from the same backend. It would be ideal for us to be able to run the rails server with SSL (so we can compare the browser output) and still have the iOS simulator connect properly without complaining about invalid certs.

Production is using a proper ssl-cert, but what's the best way to set up the simulator?

Comment: Good question as I think the answer might be that the trigger.io guys have to ignore the cert in their forge.request code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try installing the CRT file on the device like this:

- Push your CRT file to a server which your device can access to
- On the device, browse to http://example.com/certificate.crt then install the certificate.

This is similar to how you could debug SSL with proxy as described [here](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/)

Comment: You can just drag-n-drop the cert onto the simulator, too.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you can create a category around NSURLRequest that ignores certificates:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest (IgnoreSSL)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString*)host
{
  return YES;
}
@end
```

This obviously can't be submitted to the app store, and shouldn't be used in production.